# Getting text content of element node of xml

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to get the text content of first node in this XML. First node (Deductible) is an element node, when I get the text content, I get **"Calendar Year$1,500$1,500$3,000"** instead of just **"Calendar Year"**

```
<Item type="Deductible" name="Deductible" id="a">Calendar Year
<Item type="Text" name="Individual" id="b">$1,500</Item>
<Item type="Text" name="Individual Out-of-network" id="id_4">$1,500</Item>
<Item type="Text" name="Family" id="c">$3,000</Item>
<Item type="Text" name="Family Out-of-network:" id="id_5">$3,000</Item>
</Item>
```

This is what I am trying

```
dbuilder = dbc.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dbuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(plan.getProvisions())));
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("Item");
for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength(); i++){
    if(i == row){
      org.w3c.dom.Element e = (org.w3c.dom.Element)nl.item(i);
      value = e.getTextContent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code you're using. It looks like you are selecting all child nodes as well as Deductible, but without more information it's not possbible to tell. Also, your XML example is incomplete (no closing /Deductible)

Comment: I don't think it is incomplete.

Comment: Your XML is well formed, but You have mixed content, i.e., the Item element with the type, Deductible, contains both text and other Item elements. Is that intentional?

Comment: @corriganjc - Yes ..that is intentional and probably I can't change that.

Comment: In that case, you are going to have to get the first child node of the Item elements and call getNodeValue() or getTextContent() to get the text as described in the answer by @khachik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the root tag is `<Item type="Deductible" ...` you can do  `doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();`

Otherwise you can check the `type` attribute value to detect the `Item` element in the nodelist got from `getElementsByTagName("Item");`.

I would use the [Java(1.5) XPath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) API to select the `Item/@type='Deductible'` elements.

Comment: doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent(); will still get all the text because the Item with attribute deductible contains the other Item elements. Their text belongs to the Item[@type='Deductible'] as well.